# Set the desktop wallpaper using Mono

Tags: c#, linux, macos, mono

I have C# code in .NET 3.5 that sets the desktop background in Windows Vista/7.  I would like to change my code to be cross-platform Windows/Mac/Linux by tweaking it so that it can run through Mono.  The only Interop call in my code is the one to set the wallpaper.

I understand that each platform will require a different method/script for this to work; my plan is to check OS & version and run the appropriate code as needed.  So far I've found the following non-mono resources which may help:

- (Mac/Python)  [How can I programmatically change the background in Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431205/how-can-i-programatically-change-the-background-in-mac-os-x)
- (Linux/C++) [Changing wallpaper on Linux programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220826/changing-wallpaper-on-linux-programmatically)
- (Linux/Python) [How can I change my desktop background with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977694/change-desktop-background)

Several of these have answers which appear to include scripts which maybe could be executed using a call to the shell/command line in each environment through code?

How can I change the desktop background using mono in Linux and Mac environments?

Comment: I would guess that in Linux it will depend very much on the desktop used.

Comment: @AndrewJ.Brehm - Very true, but if I could find a _reasonably_ consistent method, say 2 or 3 different commands that coorespond to the top 2 window managers I would probably be happy with that.

Comment: Here is a wallpaper changing application for Gnome, maybe you can look at the code and get some ideas: https://launchpad.net/drapes

Comment: @BrianSnow - I looked through the code and I do see how they are doing it.  They use the mono GConf library and call client.set("/desktop/gnome/background/draw_background",path_to_image).  I'm sure I can make something work for gnome using this kind of method.

Answer (score 0):

**Setting the Wallpaper on a Mac with Mono**
I've put together a library called AppleScript Slim which is a C# dll that allows you to execute AppleScript from a WinForms (or really any) Mono application. 100% of the code for this project came straight from the Mono Develop source code, I just trimmed and repackaged the pieces I needed.

AppleScript Slim: https://applescriptslim.codeplex.com/

Here is the sample code on how to set the wallpaper using AppleScript I developed (and which works great):

```
string applScript =
@"set theUnixPath to POSIX file ""{0}"" as text 
tell application ""Finder"" 
set desktop picture to {{theUnixPath}} as alias 
end tell";

MonoDevelop.MacInterop.AppleScript.Run(string.Format(applScript, localPath));
```

**Setting the Wallpaper on Ubuntu with Mono**
(Work in Progress, I plan to use portions of the GCONF library for Mono as discussed in the question comments, haven't had the chance to try it yet)