How to Change Desktop Background Using C++ and X11?
I'm working on a C++ application that uses the X11 library, and I want to change the desktop background to a PNG image. I have a piece of code that loads a PNG image and displays it in a window, but I need to modify it to set the image as the desktop background instead.
Here’s the code I currently have:
#define STB_IMAGE_RESIZE_IMPLEMENTATION

#include <iostream>

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>

#include <stb_image.h>
#include <stb_image_resize2.h>

#include <png.h>

void log_error(const std::string& message) {
    std::cerr << "[ERROR] " << message << std::endl;
}

void log_info(const std::string& message) {
    std::cout << "[INFO] " << message << std::endl;
}

void load_png(const char* filename, unsigned char** image_data, int* width, int* height) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!fp) {
        log_error("Failed to open file: " + std::string(filename));
        return;
    }

    png_structp png = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (!png) {
        fclose(fp);
        log_error("Failed to create PNG read struct.");
        return;
    }

    png_infop info = png_create_info_struct(png);
    if (!info) {
        png_destroy_read_struct(&png, nullptr, nullptr);
        fclose(fp);
        log_error("Failed to create PNG info struct.");
        return;
    }

    if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png))) {
        png_destroy_read_struct(&png, &info, nullptr);
        fclose(fp);
        log_error("Error during PNG creation.");
        return;
    }

    png_init_io(png, fp);
    png_read_info(png, info);

    *width = png_get_image_width(png, info);
    *height = png_get_image_height(png, info);
    png_byte bit_depth = png_get_bit_depth(png, info);
    png_byte color_type = png_get_color_type(png, info);

    if (color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_PALETTE) {
        png_set_palette_to_rgb(png);
    }
    if (color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY && bit_depth < 8) {
        png_set_expand_gray_1_2_4_to_8(png);
    }
    if (png_get_valid(png, info, PNG_INFO_tRNS)) {
        png_set_tRNS_to_alpha(png);
    }
    if (bit_depth == 16) {
        png_set_strip_16(png);
    }

    png_set_expand(png);
    png_read_update_info(png, info);

    *image_data = (unsigned char*)malloc(png_get_rowbytes(png, info) * (*height));
    png_bytep* row_pointers = (png_bytep*)malloc(sizeof(png_bytep) * (*height));
    for (int y = 0; y < *height; y++) {
        row_pointers[y] = *image_data + y * png_get_rowbytes(png, info);
    }

    png_read_image(png, row_pointers);
    png_destroy_read_struct(&png, &info, nullptr);
    free(row_pointers);
    fclose(fp);
}

void set_background(const char* filename) {
    unsigned char* image_data = nullptr;
    int original_width, original_height;
    load_png(filename, &image_data, &original_width, &original_height);

    if (image_data == nullptr) {
        log_error("Failed to load image data.");
        return;
    }

    Display* display = XOpenDisplay(nullptr);
    if (!display) {
        log_error("Cannot open display");
        free(image_data);
        return;
    }
    log_info("Display opened successfully.");

    int screen_width = XDisplayWidth(display, DefaultScreen(display));
    int screen_height = XDisplayHeight(display, DefaultScreen(display));

    float aspect_ratio = static_cast<float>(original_width) / static_cast<float>(original_height);
    int new_width, new_height;

    if (screen_width / aspect_ratio <= screen_height) {
        new_width = screen_width;
        new_height = static_cast<int>(screen_width / aspect_ratio);
    } else {
        new_height = screen_height;
        new_width = static_cast<int>(screen_height * aspect_ratio);
    }

    unsigned char* resized_image_data = (unsigned char*)malloc(new_width * new_height * 4); // 4 for RGBA

    stbir_resize(image_data, original_width, original_height, 0, resized_image_data, new_width, new_height, 0, STBIR_RGBA, STBIR_TYPE_UINT8, STBIR_EDGE_CLAMP, STBIR_FILTER_DEFAULT);

    Window window = XCreateSimpleWindow(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), 0, 0, new_width, new_height, 0, BlackPixel(display, 0), WhitePixel(display, 0));
    XSelectInput(display, window, ExposureMask | KeyPressMask);
    XMapWindow(display, window);

    XImage* ximage = XCreateImage(display, DefaultVisual(display, 0), 24, ZPixmap, 0, (char*)resized_image_data, new_width, new_height, 32, 0);
    if (!ximage) {
        log_error("Failed to create XImage.");
        XDestroyWindow(display, window);
        XCloseDisplay(display);
        free(image_data);
        free(resized_image_data);
        return;
    }
    log_info("XImage created successfully.");

    GC gc = XCreateGC(display, window, 0, nullptr);
    if (!gc) {
        log_error("Failed to create graphics context (GC).");
        XDestroyImage(ximage);
        XDestroyWindow(display, window);
        XCloseDisplay(display);
        free(image_data);
        free(resized_image_data);
        return;
    }

    XEvent event;
    while (true) {
        XNextEvent(display, &event);
        if (event.type == Expose) {
            XPutImage(display, window, gc, ximage, 0, 0, 0, 0, new_width, new_height);
        }
        if (event.type == KeyPress) {
            break;
        }
    }

    XDestroyImage(ximage);
    XFreeGC(display, gc);
    XDestroyWindow(display, window);
    XCloseDisplay(display);
    
    log_info("Resources cleaned up and display closed.");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        log_error("Usage: " + std::string(argv[0]) + " <image.png>");
        return 1;
    }

    set_background(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}

What I Want to Achieve:
I want to modify the set_background function so that it changes the desktop background instead of just displaying the image in a window.
Questions:
How can I set the desktop background using X11?
Are there any specific functions or libraries I should use to achieve this?
What considerations should I keep in mind when changing the desktop background?

Thanks so much in advance for your help! I really appreciate any guidance or code snippets you can share. Looking forward to your responses!
I tried using the existing code to load a PNG image and display it in a window. I expected that by modifying the set_background function, I could set the loaded image as the desktop background. However, I wasn't sure how to interact with the X11 system to change the desktop background instead of just displaying it in a window.

It isn’t X11 you need to mess with, it is the window manager. IDK if there is some common protocol(s) that you can play with. This Q may be a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220826/changing-wallpaper-on-linux-programmatically

And there are so many different window managers https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Window_manager#List_of_window_managers , you could handle kde and gnome and xfce and call it a day.
